# После залива сайта на хостинг с WordPressa, перестало все работать в панели администратора

Tags: php, wordpress, хостинг, домен, поддомены

Залил все на хостинг и домен, добавил базу данных (раз 30 уже повторил это и заново на хостинг заливал), но сейчас если я захочу удалить или добавить плагин, у меня ничего не происходит. Просто нажимается и как будто кнопка статическая. Так же и со всем остальным, нельзя добавить страницу, изменить ссылку страницы и все остальное. Но при этом сам сайт работает.

Comment: Переделывай ещё раз. но теперь правильно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562

Comment: Почему это правильный вариант? Потому что так написали? При правильном варианте нужно использовать программы? Что-то не совсем похоже на правильное. Уже переносил сайт пару раз и все было хорошо, но сейчас столкнулся с таким. Спросил здесь в надежде, что кто-то с таким сталкивался и может помочь.

Comment: Там написано не только как и чем нужно делать, но и почему. Изучай.